# AB benchmark: why is my app 10 times faster increasing concurrency 10 times?

Tags: performance, ab

I don't understand very well the behavior of my web application.
It's a php web application running on Nginx.
I tried to test some simple page and I get:

```
ab -n 5000 -c 500 http://xxx
Req per sec: 600
Time per req 1.6 ms (mean across requests)

ab -n 5000 -c 100 http://xxx
Req per sec: 50
Time per req 20 ms (mean across requests)
```

I probably don't understand the result.
I thought that increasing the concurrency 10 times I would see a dramatic decrease in average request performance...where am I wrong?

Comment: That is something we can't explain either as we don't have any idea on both how your server is configured nor do we know what your code is supposed to be doing, (for all we know your code stopped working and started to return errors..) - In general you run additional monitoring on the server when you apply load to see what happens there

Comment: I think is more basic than that, I probably didnt understand properly the concurrency concept and the mean across requests...probably it's explained here http://serverfault.com/questions/274252/apache-ab-please-explain-the-output

Comment: @HBrujin ...but you are probably right, it's possible my app is "breaking" at high concurrency level so it's just returning an error very fast...

Comment: Ideally you shouldn't need to *guess*, you would *know*. start collecting logs, or increase the verbosity level of your existing logs and see what actually happens.